# How to generate request param as object in spring using habarta-typescript-generator

Tags: java, typescript, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to generated a spring endpoint that has a request param as an object (not annotated with `@RequestParam` annotation). The reason why I want to do this is because some endpoint consist of a large number of query params and I want to group then within models of their own.

Expected behaviour:

`@GetMapping("/foo") fun foo(req: RequestDTO): String`

should be generated to:
`foo(queryParams: { req: RequestDTO; }, options?: any): RestResponse<string>`

but actually generates to:
`foo(options?: any): RestResponse<string>`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass a large number of query parameters then you need to be mindful that `GET` requests have a limit of how many parameters you can pass. However, if you really need to use query parameters then you can do the following:

##### Using GET

If you want to pass an object through query parameters you can pass the properties of the object individually through the query parameters and spring will collect those and build the object for you. Just make sure the object has a public default constructor and the properties have public getter/setters, ex:

```java
public class RequestDTO {
     private String property1;
     private String property2;
     
     // make sure you have a default constructor

     // make sure you have setter/getter for the properties
}
```

Then the endpoint itself will look like:

```java
@GetMapping("/endpoint")
public ResponseEntity<String> get(RequestDTO request) {
     // ...
}
```

the request url will look something like this:

```
http://hostname/endpoint?property1=test1&property2
```

#### Using POST/PUT/PATCH

If you are able to get away from query parameters then use POST/PUT/PATCH instead. This is what it looks like:

```java
@PostMapping("/endpoint")
public ResponseEntity<String> post(@RequestBody RequestDTO request) {
     // ...
}
```

Hope this helps!